# Matching a template image in CV2 with a different orientation

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

So I'm a very experienced developer trying to get into some machine learning/neural networking code.

Essentially I need a HUGE dataset so my first problem is that I need to find a way of labelling a lot of images quickly. So take [this](https://platesmania.com/kz/nomer13145340) as the example.

I was thinking I could use template matching on the main image with the image below it? So that way I would simply need to get permission to use this data and I could label it very quickly.

When using openCV(from the examples) I get some very funky results which don't find the plate in the image, it does draw boxes but not around the plate, having tested it, it gets very very close a few times, but not much, code is...

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('./image2.jpg',0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv.imread('./Plate2.test.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
# All the 6 methods for comparison in a list
methods = ['cv.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv.TM_CCORR',
            'cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']
for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)
    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(res)
    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv.TM_SQDIFF, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)
    plt.show()
```

The first thing is I'm guessing this isn't working because the Main image we're looking for the template on is orientated differently.

The second thing I should point out is I am NOT a Python programmer so I'm learning this also, and this is my first time touching OpenCV so I'm trying to apply what I DO understanding about object detecting to things I don't properly understand.

What I want to do is get the coordinates for a bounding box in the MAIN image from the smaller plate that way I can(with permission) create a decent dataset to train really quick - otherwise, I have to do it manually :-(

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have a lot of examples working but this was an interesting problem I didn't find any reading on.

In my mind the steps are:

1)Find the plate and create bounding box

2)Train the dataset across as many images a possible for object detection on said plates

3) When testing the plate needs extracting from the main image and then a perspective transform applying.

4) If you wanted to, then you'd do text extraction once you've got the plate flattened out.

UPDATE:

So I tried SIFT from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) the results are as follows(note this image is already in the public domain from the above website.) - not quite on target!

UPDATE 2

I've managed to cobble together a solution from an article as suggested JD in the comments, essentially it lets me label enough images to create a neural network that in turn is much better at detecting them - I'll post an update soon with the answer.

[image]

Comment: Google for 'openCV number plate recognition'. You will find many projects that preform better than matchTemplate.

Comment: Template matching is mostly just for offsets and does not include rotation. If you need rotation and/or scale, then you would have to use multiple templates for each rotation angle and scale factor. You would be better off matching using feature matching using ORB, SURF or SIFT or the like. You can find those in OpenCV

Comment: @J.D. Thanks for your reply, so I have a had a look at google for this and even the open source solutions I can find are really inefficient.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for this I'll have a look!

Comment: @J.D. So turns out I've managed to adapt one of the solutions you suggested, basically I can label enough images which in turn creates a neural network which is much better at detecting the plates - I'll post an example soon!